# Is there a way to force TypeScript compiler to use RequireJs rather than Browserify when converting 'import' and 'export' keywords?

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs, browserify

I have to integrate two projects: one is built on RequireJS (it's forced by the framework) and the second one which is written in TypeScript (it has to act like a library for the first project).

But there is a problem with require(...) statement - both RequireJs and Browserify (used by TS compiler) use this keyword.

I have tried the browserify-derequire method and created one JS file from the second project but it created huge file (~2.7MB) which impacts to the performance. It also looks like derequired output JS file fails with dependencies inside it.

Comment: I think you're confusing TypeScript's CommonJS support, browserify leveraging CommonJS, as typescript support for browserify. Regardless, just use `tsc --module amd`. Typescript supports RequireJS just fine. For some reason everyone feels they need to target the CommonJS module format in TypeScript. TypeScript has a lot of other options including `--module system` which is my personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Aluan Haddad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1915893/aluan-haddad/) the `--module amd` switch is the right answer.